# C# Datatable not working after inserting multiple rows inside foreach

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, datatable

Alright, this is very weird. When I have one `<tr>` tag inside `foreach`, the datatable works perfectly:

```
<table id="table_id">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>H1</th>
                <th>H2</th>
                <th>H3</th>
                <th>H4</th>
                <th>H5</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>

            @foreach (var x in y)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>some data</td>
                    <td>some data</td>
                    <td>some data</td>
                    <td>some data</td>
                    <td>some data</td>
                </tr>
             }
    </tbody>

</table>
```

But when I add another `<tr>` in the same foreach, the datatable stops working:

```
@foreach (var x in y)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>some data</td>
                        <td>some data</td>
                        <td>some data</td>
                        <td>some data</td>
                        <td>some data</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="4">some more data</td>
                        <td>some more data</td>
                    </tr>
                 }
```

I have tried removing colspan but that's not the reason. When I remove the second `<tr>` tag it works again. Anyone have any idea what this is about?

I'm using ASP.NET with MVC4, and working on datatables with bootstrap.

Comment: What do you mean by "datatable stops working"? What exactly is your problem? Basically markup you've shown looks valid. And how is it related to C# datatables? I see only html markup for table here.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev The @ foreach shows that it is using Razor inside html. And when I say it stops working, I mean it stops working. The pagination, search bar, number of entries per page, everything disappears. There is no pagination anymore, and instead, there's a loooong list of data in the table.

Comment: Well, sample you've shown is totally valid. Probably there is a problem in your *actual* code.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev Shouldn't the problem affect when I'm using one <tr> tag as well?

Comment: It is impossible to guess without seeing actual code that causes the problem. I bet there is something more complex than string "some more data" in your real application code - so it may cause markup problems. Probably some unescaped tag in that data or something like this.

Comment: `<td colspan="5">
                    <b>Comments:</b> @delivery.deliveryComment <br />
                    <b>Receive special offers:</b> @delivery.offer_email
                </td>` that's the second row code. When I put the exact same thing in the first row, it works perfectly. @AndyKorneyev

Comment: Well, I don't see anything wrong in this markup. Problem should be somewhere in the data you're outputting. But it is only you who can debug your application and inspect the content....